# How to get unique letters from string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find how to get unique letters in a given string.

Do we have any inbuilt method to get it?

**My code:**

```
strname='aavccbb'
strname.most_common()
```

**Expected output:**

```
abcv
```

I would have made use of `set` but there is no guarantee of order.

Comment: `''.join(sorted(set(strname)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# Long form
strname='aavccbb'
lst = list(strname)
lst.sort()
print(set(lst))

# Short form
print(sorted(set(list(strname))))
```